# I need to take the inner contents of the JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring

**I have the following code to Retrieve the JSON response from server and it is working fine.**

Javascript Code :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://***SOMEURL',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify(data)   
})
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    $scope.myData1=response.data.message.connectionDetailses;
});
```

And the response is

```
{
    "code": 100,
    "message": {
        "id": 29020,
        "customerCode": "730",
        "name": "John P. M.    168",
        "lastName": "X",
        "houseName": "Hosuseahjkahsh",
        "address1": "1",
        "address2": "x",
        "address3": "wehwhkjwh P. O.",
        "postalCode": "686011",
        "email": "11@11.com",
        "phone": "1234567890",
        "mobile": "1234567890",
        "operatorName": "abcd ",
        "connectionDetailses": [
            {
                "customerCode": "730",
                "accountId": 5,
                "dueAmount": 0,
                "connectionId": 27203,
                "accountName": "M S"
            },
            {
                "customerCode": "730",
                "accountId": 5,
                "dueAmount": 2000,
                "connectionId": 116303,
                "accountName": "MS"
            },
            {
                "customerCode": "730",
                "accountId": 9,
                "dueAmount": 0,
                "connectionId": 116303,
                "accountName": "Connection"
            },
            {
                "customerCode": "730",
                "accountId": 14,
                "dueAmount": 0,
                "connectionId": 116303,
                "accountName": "Amc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to print the connection details based on the connectionId. I am able to print all connection details at a time. But I need to print the details within a single block.

```
{
                "customerCode": "730",
                "accountId": 9,
                "dueAmount": 0,
                "connectionId": 116303,
                "accountName": "Connection"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a connectionId, you can print corresponding connection detail by:

```
let connectionId = 116303
let connectionDetail = response.data.message.connectionDetailses.find(det => det.connectionId === connectionId);
console.log(connectionDetail);
```

In case you want to get all details based on the same id, you can use array.filter:

```
let connectionId = 116303
let connectionDetails = response.data.message.connectionDetailses.filter(det => det.connectionId === connectionId);
console.log(connectionDetails);
```

Comment: But i have 3 connections on id 116303. How can i get all 3 details based on the same id?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: how to calculate sum of  dueAmount from the selected details?

Comment: You can just use array.reduce:

var dueAmountSum = connectionDetails.reduce((total, det) => (total + det.dueAmount), 0);

Answer (score 0):

i guess, you could use `Array#filter` to filter only the connections with the needed id. something like:

```
const details = response.data.message.connectionDetailses
  .filter(connection => connection.connectionId === 116303)[0]
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. but still not working. :(